# Does PECL Stem Work with PHP CLI?

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a background process that stems words using PHP CLI. I originally have used this stemmer, written in c (https://github.com/hthetiot/php-stemmer) - the problem however is that it will not work when executed via command line, only via the browser. I get an undefined function error. Before going threw the process of adding in a new module, I was hoping someone using it might already know if this is even possible. I'm aware of pure PHP implementations, but prefer the speed of a c extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just found my system has two separate php.ini files, one for CLI, the other Apache. Just had to add the extension to the CLI ini.